# php DateTime diff method behavior

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval, date-math

I have to find the days until an expiration date.
I tried to use diff method of DateTime class.

```
$dataexp = 2013-11-06 00:00:00 ;
$now = 2013-11-05 13:00:00 ;

$dtn = new DateTime('now');
$dte = new DateTime($dataexp);

$diff = $dtn->diff($dte);

$days = sprintf("%01d", $diff->days);

$days ---> display 1
```

My problem is if the dataexp is in the past of 1 day the result of diff is 1 and not -1

```
$dataexp = 2013-11-04 00:00:00 ;
$now = 2013-11-05 13:00:00 ;

$dtn = new DateTime('now');
$dte = new DateTime($dataexp);

$days = sprintf("%01d", $diff->days);

$days ---> display 1
```

What method could I use to get what I want? (-1 days)? Thanks

Comment: `diff` needs formatting to show the proper value. #Look at the examples in the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: "`display 1`" - what does that mean exactly? The code you show displays nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**`DateInterval::format()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php), specifically the `r` format character.

```
echo $diff->format('%r%d');
```

Comment: It works, but if $dataexp = 2013-11-05 12:00:00 $diff->format('%r%d') display -0

Comment: That's because of your time values. I'd remove them before doing your date math.

Comment: Can I remove the time of my date with DateTime class?

Comment: I *think* using something like `$dtn->modify('midnight')` will work but that's just a guess and untested. If you're getting your values from a DB you can remove them in your query. If you use MySQL you can use the `DATE()` function to trim the time values.

Comment: mmm I 've a problem if my $dataexpp = 2014-02-03 00:00:00, $diff->format('%r%d') display 28. Why??

Comment: That's because `%d` will only show up to 31 days. After that you need to start using other flags like `%m` for months, too.

Comment: Ok, but if I display only the days? it is possible? I must display -1 or 1 or 20 or 60 days.

Comment: Try using `$diff->r` with `$diff->days`